# Can Visual Studio 2022 run libraries made in 2014?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libraries

I found a library that converts .WAV files to .Ogg in C++, but that library was made in 2014, so I was wondering whether it would still work in Visual Studio 2022. Here is the link - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/824199/The-OGG-Wrapper-An-audio-converter

Comment: Sure, you just need to create a c++ project in Visual Studio 2022 and copy/ paste the code if just importing leads to errors.

Comment: Be a bit more precise in what you mean. Do you want to recompile the library or link with it?  If you want to link you need to check if there is ABI compatibility between the visual studio versions : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170.

Comment: Have you tried it? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: *UPDATE* I have tried it, but I get numerous errors. I have attached a screenshot below  https://imgur.com/a/v6zleH1

Comment: You could try to improve the compatibility of the library in the compiler of the development library first, and then link with other compiler.